How to port Buffer.from() to deno2
Rewriting a webapp so that it can run in both Node or Deno2, I get stuck on the following. The function has to read a base64 encoded gzip buffer containing a JSON string. This is the node implementation:
import zlib from 'node:zlib';

function from_base64_gzip(str){
  let buff = Buffer.from(str, 'base64');
  let json = zlib.unzipSync(buff).toString('utf-8');
  return JSON.parse(json);
}

However deno2 does not have the Buffer object, and atob() only seems to work for strings and not for binary data.
Is there an elegant way to rewrite this such that it will run both in node and deno (preferably without extra npm deps)?

atob() only seems to work for strings makes sense, since it converts from base64, which is traditionally a string - have you tried import { Buffer } from "node:buffer"; as documented?

Ok you are correct  I was using Import Buffer instead of Import { Buffer}. Can you reference this documentation because I was unable to find it.

it's on the documentation landing page https://docs.deno.com/

https://docs.deno.com/api/node/buffer/

Can the function become asynchronous? If so, zlib is not needed: there are globals available in all of the described environments (including web browsers) to handle this operation asynchronously without dependencies.

The answer was given in the comments: we can import the node buffer API as documented:
import { Buffer } from "node:buffer";
import zlib from 'node:zlib';

function from_base64_gzip(str){
  let buff = Buffer.from(str, 'base64');
  let json = zlib.unzipSync(buff).toString('utf-8');
  return JSON.parse(json);
}

Note that Buffer is not the default export, hence we have to use import { Buffer } instead of import Buffer, which is why I initially thought it did not work.

As of Deno 2.1, you can now use the Buffer global variable as long as you do two steps:

Use the new --unstable-node-globals flag
(if you depend on Typescript type checking) add the Buffer global variable to your typescript file

declare global {
  type Buffer = typeof import("node:buffer").Buffer;
}

You can find the exact PR that added this feature here

A method that works in Deno, Node and the browser would be to use the decodeBase64 function from jsr:@std/encoding, and toBytes from jsr:@std/streams/unstable-to-bytes. With these two dependencies, and the global DecompressionStream, one can construct the below function.
import { decodeBase64 } from "@std/encoding";
import { toBytes } from "@std/streams/unstable-to-bytes";

const text = "H4sIAAAAAAAAE6tWyk0tLk5MT1WyUvJIzcnJVwjPL8pJUVSqBQBrh/YJGgAAAA==";
console.log(await fromBase64Gzip(text)); // { message: 'Hello World!' }

export async function fromBase64Gzip(str) {
  return JSON.parse(
    new TextDecoder().decode(
      await toBytes(
        ReadableStream.from([decodeBase64(str)]).pipeThrough(
          new DecompressionStream("gzip"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

The only difference between the output of these two functions is that this one is asynchronous and yours in synchronous.
